# Add List<Widget> to ListView.children dynamically

Tags: listview, dart, flutter

I am trying to dynamically build part of my `ListView.children[]`, yet I fail to push them to already existing array. Here is my simplified code:

```
  Widget buildNavigationDrawer(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(...code for header of drawer),

          _buildUserGroups(context).map((Widget item)=> item),

          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            title: Text('Settings'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  FadeTransitionRoute(
                      builder: (context) => MainSettingsPage()));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Where `_buildUserGroups()` function looks like this (simplified):

```
  List<Widget> _buildUserGroups(BuildContext context) {
    var userGroup = List<Widget>();
    userGroup.add(Text("Users"));

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      userGroup.add(Text("User " + i.toString()));
    }

    return userGroup;
  }
```

I have tried to use `_buildUserGroups(context).forEach()`, `_buildUserGroups(context).map()`, or simply dumping the result like `_buildUserGroups(context)`; yet it fails and says the same error message:

> [dart] The element type 'Iterable' can't be assigned to the
>   list type 'Widget'.

I am quite sure the is a way how to do it, but I cannot figure it out. Any help or suggestion in respect to this matter would be highly appreciated as I am quite stuck at the moment.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As pointed out by other answers, the `_buildUserGroups(context)` is the problem, as it returns a list of widgets, resulting in a nested list.

Since Dart 2.3 (introduced to Flutter at Google I/O '19), you can use the **spread operator `...`**, which will unwrap the inner list, so its elements become elements of the outer list:

```dart
Widget buildNavigationDrawer(BuildContext context) {
  return Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      children: [
        DrawerHeader(...),
        ..._buildUserGroups(context),
        ListTile(...)
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

For more information about what the spread operator does, check out [Dart's language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists).

---

**Original answer (before Dart 2.3):**

You can wrap the function call in a `Column` or `ExpansionTile`.

**However**, this introduces a new widget into the widget tree.
Admittedly, the impact on performance is minimal, but in my opinion, a cleaner solution would be to construct the list of widgets like this:

```dart
Widget buildNavigationDrawer(BuildContext context) {
  final items = <Widget>[]
    ..add(DrawerHeader(...))
    ..addAll(_buildUserGroups(context))
    ..add(ListTile(...));

  return Drawer(child: ListView(children: items));
}
```

If you insist on an inline solution, you can also use `.followedBy(...)` to add items to the list:

```dart
Widget buildNavigationDrawer(BuildContext context) {
  return Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      children: [ DrawerHeader(...) ]
        .followedBy(_buildUserGroups(context))
        .followedBy([ ListTile(...) ])
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of followedBy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I over-complicated my thinking so much, I could not see that had a simple solution right in front of me all the time. I ended up wrapping it in the `Column` widget which solved the problem:

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: _buildUserGroups(context),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

## Wrap it with ExpansionTile or Column

**Problem:**

```
_buildUserGroups(context).map((Widget item)=> item),
```

**Solution: 1**

```
ExpansionTile(
     title: Text("New List"),
     children:  _buildUserGroups(context).map((Widget item)=> item),
   )
```

**Solution: 2**

```
Column(
     children:  _buildUserGroups(context).map((Widget item)=> item),
   )
```

**Note:**
Iterable only assigned to `Children:` because it gets a `List<Widget>`. You are setting iterable for single child `widget`, that is why you are getting error.

I hope this solve your problem. Happy Coding!!