# How to place an image below a listview in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Using this simple design, how can I display the second image under the listview? In reality the list will be fetched from firebase where each item is an ExpansionTile, so the height of the listview can in no way be fixed.

The column should be scrollable so you can see the full image if you scroll down below the list.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

List<Widget> list = <Widget>[
  ListTile(
    title: Text('CineArts at the Empire',
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20.0)),
    subtitle: Text('85 W Portal Ave'),
    leading: Icon(
      Icons.theaters,
      color: Colors.blue[500],
    ),
  ),
  ListTile(
    title: Text('The Castro Theater',
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20.0)),
    subtitle: Text('429 Castro St'),
    leading: Icon(
      Icons.theaters,
      color: Colors.blue[500],
    ),
  ),
];

class CartWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
      Image.network("https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          children: list,
        ),
      ),
      Image.network("https://via.placeholder.com/350x500"), // error: hides above widget
    ]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understood your problem is that you want the bottom image to appear inside the list view instead of under it, *as if it was just another item*. Solution: **Make it just another item!**

More concrete, this is how your implementation for a helper function that enriches the list with the image may look like:

```
List<Widget> _buildListWithFooterImage(List<Widget> items) {
  return items.followedBy([
    Image.network("https://via.placeholder.com/350x500")
  ]);
}
```

Then, you could use that function during your build:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.network("https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            children: _buildListWithFooterImage(list)
         )
        ),
      ]
    )
  );
}
```

Also, I believe your question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52801075/).

Comment: Thanks... though it seems like a hack to place the image inside the listview. Wouldn't any column child after the listview be hidden, with your solution?

Comment: Not at all! During layout, the `Column` lays out its children in the following order: First inflexible ones (like the top image or anything custom below the `ListView`) and only after that flexible ones (like the `Expanded` widget). So the `ListView` always takes the rest of the available space, not more and not less.

Comment: I guess listviews are not intended to be in columns then? In my case the list was generated with .toList(), so .followedBy didn't work, but I got it to work using .toList() + [Image.network(...)]

Comment: Ooh cool, I didn't know `List`s override the `+` operator... good to know. And yes, while you can compose widgets very flexibly in Flutter, `ListView`s are not intended to be used as direct children to `Column`s. The reason is that `ListView`s take all the available space they can and `Column`s provide each child with infinite height constraints as a way to communicate with them to be as small as possible. For more information, have a look at [this interesting Google Tech Talk about Flutter's rendering pipeline](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUfXWzp0-DU).